# Confused about double Colon RSYNC over SSH

Tags: rsync

I have read that RSYNC over SSH requires a single colon `:` after USER@HOST, whereas connecting directly to a daemon require a double colon `::`. However in order to get my RSYNC command line to work shown below, i have to use a double colon?? Can someone please explain this? `download` is the name of the remote virtual directory.

Cheers,

```
rsync -trv --progress --timeout=10 -e 'ssh -p 46000' hexfeed@11.22.33.44::download /tmp/test1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::` tells this rsync command to expect the remote to be already running a daemon, but the `-e` then says that instead of opening a network connection to the given server at the default port of 873, it should run the command `ssh...` to create the connection and expect a daemon at the other end.

This can only work if the remote runs a command like `rsync --server --daemon --config=somefile .` when you login via `ssh -p 46000`.

Comment: So would it be possible to drop 1 of the colons and target a specific source dir on the remote host rather than the running daemon/virtual dir? Just wrapping my head around this.

Comment: Normally, if you can ssh at the usual port of 22, and get a shell prompt then you would expect to be able to rsync with `:` (and without `-e`). In that case rsync will automatically run `rsync --server` on the remote. You can see the remote command being sent with `--debug=CMD2`

Comment: Ah ok, in this instance i am using 46000 and just re routing it at the firewall to the host on port 22.